# how to add the dynamically added input elements as parameter using jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Iam new to jquery. I have a rails form. where iam going to add/edit a list.

```
     <%@mylist.each_with_index do |list, index|%>
       <tr>
          <td width="40" >
           <%= text_field_tag :"question_#{list.fact_number}", "#{list.question}" ,:size=>"20"%>
         </td>
      </tr>
   <%end%>
  <% @listno = list.fact_number %>


<input type="button" value="Add New Fact" id="addchbutton" onclick="addrow(this.form, <%= @listno%> )" />
```

In in the script i add a new row to the table on button click. iam generating the id for the new element...say the last element id is question_5. the new row input element will have the id as question_6.

var listno, factnumber;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
listno = <%=  @listno.to_json %>;
;
 });

     function addrow(myform, fact_number){
        id = factno;
        var value = "<tr>"+
              `"<td><input type=\"checkbox\" checked=\"true\" size=\"20\" ``id=\"save_status_"+id+"\"/></td>"+`
```

"`<td><input type=\"text\" size=\"20\" id=\"question_"+id+"\"/></td>"+ "</tr>";`

```
       $('#mytable tr:last').after(value);
      }
```

On sumbitting the form. iam not getting the newly added rows in the params. Any idea how to add the new rows to form. ie params[:question_5] is availabe but params[:question_6] is nil. am i missing something? please help. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to give the new input a name attribute:

```
<input id="someid" type="checkbox" name="inputname" />
```